# How can I fix error React Routr 6.6 +TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem with using React router 6.6 and Typescript.

I installed React router and added it to Index.js like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { router } from './router';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  ....
);

root.render(
  <RouterProvider router={router}>
    <App />
  </RouterProvider>
);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLypN.png)

And I'm getting this error:

> Type '{ children: Element; router: Router; }` is not assignable to
> type 'IintrinsicAttributes & RouterProviderProps'.   Property
> 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
> RouterProviderProps'. ts(2322)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI3u5.png)

How can I fix this issue?

I was expecting to work react router with standard way, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Data routers work a little differently from the older conventional routers. See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) for more details on the new Data APIs and syntax. Also check the [RouterProvider](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider) component docs.

The `RouterProvider` component takes no `children`, so remove `App` as a child component.

```
root.render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);
```

If you still need to render `App` somewhere it'll need to be moved into the `router` object you created with `createBrowserRouter` (*or similar*).

Comment: Thank you very much. If I need to load context api provider component ,  <AppContextProvider> , where I should write it ?

Comment: @JahangirKazimli `AppContextProvider` can wrap `RouterProvider` or you can create a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) to render it. It only needs to be rendered into the ReactTree above any other component that needs to access the context value it provides.

Comment: How about when doing UI tests on a component that uses the `<Link>` element? The test doesn't work unless the component is wrapped inside a `<RouterProvider />`. With that wrapped around the component, the test does work, but outputs a typescript error about `children`.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen The `Link` component only requires a routing context, and for this any router will work. In unit tests we typically use the `MemoryRouter`. If you have a specific testing issue that you need help resolving then it may be more beneficial to create a new SO post for it. If you do create a post feel free to ping me again here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen Welcome, glad to help.